# TYPO3 8.6 categories in CEs

Tags: typo3

can you please tell me what is the adequate way to get the categories of a CE element in a fluid template ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i did it that way in the TS:

```
lib.categories = CONTENT
lib.categories {
    table = sys_category
    select {
        pidInList = 1
        selectFields = sys_category.uid
        join = sys_category_record_mm on sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = sys_category.uid
        where.field = recordUid
        where.wrap = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign=|
    }
    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
        1 = TEXT
        1 {
            field = uid
            stdWrap.noTrimWrap = |
        }
    }
}
```

And that way in the fluid template:

```
<div class="wrapper {f:if(condition: '{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: \'lib.categories\', data: {recordUid: data.uid})} == 2', then: 'category', else: 'default')}"></div>
```